# Using Clojure's Persistent Collections in Java

Tags: java, collections, clojure, thread-safety

I really like Clojure's Persistent (copy-on-write) collections and would like to use them, but I'm not yet ready to switch to Clojure itself.

How do I use the Collections inside Java code? (There has to be a way right? Since these are all just java classes in the end.)

Alternatively, is there any other implementation of a thread-safe hashmap with similar semantics for Java?

Comment: I assume ConcurrentHashMap is no good for you?

Comment: @EricStein: I don't know. It seems difficult to find information on how the default ConcurrentHashMap works.

Comment: @amalloy: Yes, that answers the question.